# xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',token ) works in dev but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In my Rails  app i have an action that make ajax request. When i make this ajax request, Setting CSRF token with  xhr.setRequestHeader works fine in development but in production (heroku) doesn't. What could be possibly a problem?  or how do i debug thisin firebug?

Here is my ajax setup

```
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
 'beforeSend': function(xhr, settings) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  var token=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',token );
  settings['dataType'] = "json";
  settings['contentType'] = "application/json";
  }
 });
```

Comment: did you have %= csrf_meta_tag %> in your layout?

Comment: To make sure token is set console.log(token)

Comment: I have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in application layout

Comment: set console.log("beforeSend invoke") in beforeSend to make sure function even invoke

Comment: in development environment did message "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" appears?

Comment: No i dont get that warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figured it out, for this to work in production i had to configure the production domain in `session_store.rb` as follows

```
   YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
   {key: '_yourApp_session', domain: '.yourDomain.com'}
```